# level 2 of angular.js tutorial

Tags: angularjs

i just saw this in the angular.js tutorial on the level 2:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

  app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    this.products = gems;
  });

  app.controller("TabController", function(){
    this.tab = 1;

    this.setTab = function(selectedTab){
      this.tab = selectedTab;
    };
  });

  var gems = [// a lot of code here...]
})();
```

my doubt is: how does the setTab function alter the value of the TabControler's tab variable? if I use 'this.tab' in the setTab function, the setTab function will be just assigning a variable to it's own internal scope, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I use 'this.tab' in the setTab function, the setTab function will
>   be just assigning a variable to it's own internal scope, doesn't it?

Actually, no.

`this`, inside your `setTab` function is a reference some particular instance of the `TabController`. So, `this.tab`, means "the tab property of the TabController instance". This instance will be created by Angular internals to handle the view, so you just don't worry about this part.

Edit:

You can use this an example:

```
var MyConstructor = function() { 
    this.tab = 0;
    this.setTab = function(newTab) {
        this.tab = newTab;
    }; 
    this.logTab = function() {
        console.log(this.tab);
    };
};

var myObj = new MyConstructor();
myObj.logTab(); // prints 0
myObj.setTab(2);
myObj.logTab(); // prints 2
```

But, as dave mentioned, I would stick with the $scope approach.

Comment: It is confusing. It's like I need to force myself to forget some javascript fundamentals in order to use angular.js

Comment: @andre, this is a JavaScript fundamental, is not a Angular thing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at how angular calls the function internally - it uses something like

```
app.controller("TabController").setTab.apply($scope, [selectedTab])
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Which calls your `setTab` function, but sets the value of `this` to the `$scope` object.

It's a little more complicated than that, but that is the "how".

In general, I prefer to use the `$scope` object in my controllers, as it is and feels a little less "magic".

```
app.controller("TabController", function($scope){
    $scope.tab = 1;

    $scope.setTab = function(selectedTab){
        $scope.tab = selectedTab;
    };
});
```

For some more information, this question explains it pretty well:
['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)

To see how `fn.apply` works, here is a simple example:

```
x = function() { alert(this.test); } 
x(); //alerts "undefined"
x.apply({test: 'hello!'}); //alerts "hello!"
```

Comment: :@ I don't like this. I'm confuse